# A system with two dual-core processors has four processors threads numbers

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, multiprocessing

While I was reading the "Operating System Concepts by Abraham Silberschatz - 10th edition" book, I found a question on chapter 4 exercises, number 16. I tried to figure out the answer to that question, but I found that all online resources represented another answer.

**My answer:** For the second part of the question: we will have 8 threads maximum as we have 4 processors each of dual-core so we have a total of 8 cores. And, we can create threads as many as the processing cores. Due to the working system is a one-to-one model as stated in the question, the user-level thread is mapped to a kernel-level thread, so, we can schedule each thread on multiple processors not only one processor.

I would like to know the answer to that question as I am so confused with online answers that state the threads are only 4.

**The Question:**
A system with two dual-core processors has four processors available for scheduling. A CPU-intensive application is running on this system. All input is performed at the program start-up when a single file must be opened. Similarly, all output is performed just before the program terminates, when the program results must be written to a single file. Between start-up and termination, the program is entirely CPU-bound. Your task is to improve the performance of this application by multithreading it. The application runs on a system that uses the one-to-one threading model (each user thread maps to a kernel thread).
• How many threads will you create to perform the input and output? Explain.
• How many threads will you create for the CPU-intensive portion of the application? Explain.

Comment: The question says the system has "two dual-core processors", which means 4 cores total (2 cores on each of two chips).  Hence 4 threads.  The question is poorly worded in that it says it has "two dual core-processors" and then says "four *processors* available"; I think they meant to say "four *cores* available".

Comment: Many thanks. I got it.

Comment: I don't understand this concept of mapping user threads to kernel threads. What does mapping a thread to another thread means. Honestly, I think your book is basically a good way to waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

i) It only makes sense to create as many threads as there are blocking system calls,
as the threads will be spent blocking. Creating additional threads provides no
benefit. Thus, it makes sense to create a single thread for input and a single
thread for output.

ii) Four. There should be as many threads as there are processing cores.
Fewer would be a waste of processing resources, and any number > 4 would be
unable to run.